# Pairing a char and a number within multiple files

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am very new to c++, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have a console based game, were you input a score, and a name once you complete the game. The scores are in files that look like

```
4
6
3
```

So pretty simple. The names are formatted the same way, looking like this

```
Dylan
Justin
Drew
```

When the scores are displayed, they look like this

```
 Dylan 4
 Justin 6
 Drew 3
```

The code I have to display this is:

```
        infile.open("name.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

        ofile.open("points.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

        while (getline(infile, STRINGT) && getline(ofile, STRINGO))

        {

            cout << STRINGT << ' ';

            cout << STRINGO << '\n';

        }

        infile.close();

        ofile.close();

        _getch();
```

I want to sort the scores least to greatest (lower points is better). My original plan was to take the scores and put them in an array, then organize from there, but my problem is that I don't know how to sort the names along with the scores. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a struct like :

```
struct result {

string name;
int score
```

}

```
int number;
string word;
```

and then you create a vector of that struct,let's say with size 100 elements : `vector<result>myvector(100)`

parse the elements as word and integer:

```
infile>>word    ofile>>number
```

then add the values inside as :`myvector.name[0]="name"` and `myvector.score[0]=value`

to print out you can do it as :

```
cout<<myvector.name[0]="name"`<<" "<< `myvector.score[0]=value<<endl;
```

note: to sort the elements in the vector use `sort(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());`

Comment: Ahh, structs, should've though of that, I've never used vectors before, should I just use what you have up here and see if that works?

Comment: I ve just given couple of examples but the idea is to create struct like that and put them in a vector but if you dont know about vectors then I suggest you would first take a look at the vector concept